# How to refresh UITableView from current screen

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am using `UITableView` inside `UINavigationController`.

On First Screen I have a table view with names, alen, john, smith. and they are 3 records. Now I went onto second screen and i update the names of all three records from Database. 
In my First controller where `UITableView` is displayed i have used `[seld.tableView reloadData]` inside the `viewWillApear` delegate method. and whenever i come back to that first screen my `viewWIllApear` delegatemethod calls and my `UITableView` refreshes itself.

Now the problem is if i call `[self.tableview reloadData]` from any of my own method not from `viewWIllApear`. it does call my `ViewDidLoad` method but it does not call my uitableView delegates to update my records. 
PLease any one can help how can I update my tableView by remaining onto the Same Screen. ?

Thanks alot

**EDITED:**

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    }
```

This is my ViewDidappear method. what I want is that whenever i click on any button remaining onto the same UITableView screen it should reload my tableView rather there is any change in the Data Array or not.

Comment: show some of ur code pls

Answer (score 0):

where are these buttons in the structure? are they created programmatically? 
are they uibutton subclasses? 
i.e. where are the methods you are calling? it sounds like you are having a problem referencing the tableViewController from your own methods?

maybe you should create a method on the tableViewController and then call that from the button. please show your method code and an give an indication of what files the methods are in.

Answer (score 0):

Example A : You create your button or everything else could trigger an action in interface builder. Inside the viewController that holds the tableview use a method like the following :

```
- (IBAction)updateTable:(id)sender
{
    [self.tableview reloadData];
}
```

Obviously you have to connect the outlet with the action in IB.

Example B : You create your button programmatically.

```
// inside your loadView or viewDidLoad method
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
       action:@selector(updateTable)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,hieght);
[yourView addSubview:button];
```

In your ViewController :

```
-(void)updateTable
{
   [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `UITableViewDelegate` methods aren't begin called, then either your `tableView` outlet isn't set, or the `tableView` doesn't have `delegate` set.  As you seem to have multiple view controllers (one with the tableView, the other with the UIButtons), then you should consider also how best to communicate between the view controller - by passing the tableView (breaks encapsulation, so not good), via a delegate/protocol method call, via `NSNotification`, or some other appropriate means.

Comment: but my uitableview outlet is set. it actually loads the data whenever my Screen is reappeared. Then Y it is not being refreshed when i call [self.tableView reloadData] ???

Comment: I suggest you run the debugger with a breakpoint on that line, and check the value of [self tableView], then [[self tableView] delegate].  If this is in a separate view controller from the table view and delegate code, which you imply, then the values won't be set.